# Stacked bar chart with real values in y-axis using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, stacked-chart

I have tried stacked bar chart and wanted to get the real values, instead of placing bars one over the other. for example if Ac energy consumption is 193 at empty load and 175 in non ac energy consumption at empty load, then i desired to have a plot that shows the same values instead of piling one over the other where the y axis values goes to around 350. i dont want this type of graph: 
[image]

The sample data is here:

```
a<-tribble(
~"para",       ~"energy", ~"type",

  "Empty_Load",    175, "NoAC",   
 "Half_Load"  ,   184, "NoAC",     
 "Full_Load"   ,  191, "NoAC",    
 "Empty_Load"   , 193, "AC",       
 "Half_Load"     ,206, "AC",       
 "Full_Load"     ,211, "AC"   
)
```

and this is what i tried :

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=para,y=energy))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=type))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=para,y=energy))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=type), position ="dodge") #add position = "dodge" to place bars next to each other
```

Or like this if you want a stacked chart with the values in presented in the graph:

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=para,y=energy))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=type)) + #add position = "dodge" to place bars next to each other
  geom_text(aes(label = energy), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks @dominik, but is it possible to have stacked bar graph without dodge position, but with real values ?

Comment: What do you mean with "real values"?

Comment: You could add the values to the plot (see second option in updated answer)

Comment: For example the real value for ac is 193 in empty load but in the graph it is added with the non ac (175). i dont want an added one rather i want a graph which has ac and non ac superimposed over each other such that it shows the real values as 175 and 193

Comment: This should not be done since the y-axis loses it's meaning and the plot becomes hard to understand. I think the best way to achieve something close to what you want is to add the values directly to the plot as I did in the second example.